# Find a word that contains the vowels a , e , i , o and u , one each, in that order

Tags: python

```
vowels = "aeiouy"
with open('dictionary.txt') as fp:
    for line_str in fp:
        line_str = line_str.strip().lower()
        apos = line_str.find('a')
        epos = line_str.find('e')
        ipos = line_str.find('i')
        opos = line_str.find('o')
        upos = line_str.find('u')
```

How do i record positions in variables and print them in the order based on the value of position?

Comment: Someone asked this exact question yesterday. It's this homework?

Comment: *is. And what have you tried?

Comment: Why "y" is present in your vowel string?

Comment: This is practice for an exam. Also, I am not sure how to use an if statement to compare positions. I made the pos = 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. And the y presented in the vowel string is a mistake.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri 'y' is often considered a vowel. Iirc, whether it not it is depends on the context that it's used.

Comment: @mee @mee Try putting the positions in a list, then loop over the list. If every position is `<' the last, return true.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC , you need to get all positions of each vowels in a string\line of a file.
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) has been used for looping through each character of the string and checks if the character matches to vowels.

```
vowels = "aeiou"
fp='''habsafkbasf\n
asfgnkalsgna\n
asglkasgnn\
'''
for line_str in fp.split('\n'):
    line_str = line_str.strip().lower()
    print line_str
    for c in vowels:
        print c, ":", [pos for pos, char in enumerate(line_str) if char == c]
```

Output

```
habsafkbasf
a : [1, 4, 8]
e : []
i : []
o : []
u : []

a : []
e : []
i : []
o : []
u : []
asfgnkalsgna
a : [0, 6, 11]
e : []
i : []
o : []
u : []

a : []
e : []
i : []
o : []
u : []
asglkasgnn
a : [0, 5]
e : []
i : []
o : []
u : []
```